# Using "cases" inside "equation" gives error[with "amsmath" loaded]

Tags: equations, cases

I'm trying to use the `cases` environment inside an `equation` environment.
The sample code is quite simple:

```
\begin{equation*}
        X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
                        1 \text{se $\omega \in A$} \\
                        0 \text{se $\omega \in A^c$}
                    \end{cases}

\end{equation*}
```

Compiling it with Kile results in this error:

```
Missing $ inserted
```

and some other messages about ending delimiters not present.

I have `\usepackage{amsmath}` at the beginning of my document.

Also I must tell you that I have an other piece of code, which is identical, and which works fine:

```
 \begin{equation*}
  B_i = \begin{cases}
        A_i^c \text{se $i \in I$,}
        \\
        A_i \text{se $i \in I \smallsetminus I'$}.
        \end{cases}
 \end{equation*}
```

Also this piece gave me some errors the other day, then I changed the `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` to `$$` and `$$` and it worked.
Replace `$$` with the equation environment and the error was magically gone.

I've already tried doing this with that piece of code, but nothing changes.

Comment: Try delimiting the error; it's probably due to something that comes before that `cases` environment. You should be putting `&` in front of `\text`, but this isn't related to the error.

Comment: Right now I realized that removing the blankline between `\end{cases}` and `\end{equation*}` fixes this issue.
But I'm still interested in why something like this happens.
I'll do some tests when I've got time, maybe this error is caused by the `defn` environment I'm using(defined using `\newtheorem`).

Comment: @Bakuriu, you are aright. I got the same error with the blank line. Maybe this line is interpreted as a new line for equation and should be non empty.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In the displaymath mode, you can not use any paragraph triggering commands such as blank lines or `\par` commands. (Not a good idea, but  you can use it inside the cases environment). Also you don't need to switch to text mode and then again to math mode. You can just use text on the text and leave the rest as it is.

Another point is the use of `&` characters which is the column delimiter that should be used inside the `cases` environment. This would be apparent if one of the cases starts with `1250` and the other is `1` which would lead to a bad alignment (try without the `&` characters!).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{se $\omega\in A$}\\
1250 &\text{se $\omega \in A^c$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools)package provides some nice extensions and bugfixes of [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath), so here is an example of `dcases*` environment which automatically switches to text mode in the second entry of the case declaration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
X(\omega) = \begin{dcases*}
1 & se $\omega\in A$\\
0 & se $\omega \in A^c$
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using the `standalone` class (which gives errors) then you have to use it as

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
```

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I guess that the author edited the code in his question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I did not think that leaving blank lines in math mode would cause such troubles. I thought that they'd simply be ignored.

Comment: Missing a \ in `1 &\text{se $\omega\in A$}\ ` at the very end.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the `mathtools` package, its `dcases` environment has helped me properly format some big equations.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that `\begin{cases}` wants to be wrapped in $ to not generate an error.  I am just learning LaTeX, but when I make sure to being and `\end{cases}` within a math environment, my error goes away.

Comment: In the original posting, the `cases` environment was contained in an `equation*` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package and automatically initiates (and terminates) *displaymath*. *displaymath* material is typeset centered on a separate line (or lines) by itself. The issue with the OP's code was not a missing switch to a math environment but, rather, the fact that the `amsmath` package doesn't permit blank lines in a `displaymath` setting. In contrast, you seem to be proposing a switch to an `inline math` environment, which will *not* display its contents centered.

Comment: \begin{equation}
\label{c5:eqn5}
fit_{new} =
    $\begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{1 + f_{new}}  & \text{if  f_{new}  \geq 0}\\
      1 + |f_{new}|  & \text{if  f_{new} \leq 0}\\
     \end{cases}$    
\end{equation}

Comment: my \text{if  f_{new} \leq 0}   should be written as text{if} f_{new} \leq 0

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex/240870