# How can I write cases with grouping braces on both left and right side, and split the condition into two lines in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, cases

The code I used to write

[image: this]

is this one

```
$$
X(m,n)=
\begin{cases}
x(n),\\
x(n-1)\\
x(n-1)
\end{cases}
$$
```

But I don't know how to write this one

[image]

---

Also, what if I want to write this

[image]

Comment: I think array is suitable for this case.

Comment: Combination of: [How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47170/5764) and [How to put a brace on the right, not left, to group cases?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47560/5764)

Comment: Also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: how does one do it with a single curly bracket in front?

Comment: @CharlieParker (old comment but // also for future users in case they come across this question somehow) [conditionals - Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/large-braces-for-specifying-values-of-variables-by-condition)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \[
    X(m,n) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        x(n), & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq 1\\
        x(n-1), & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq 1\\
        x(n-1), & \text{for } 0\leq n\leq 1
        \end{array}\right\} = xy
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want two conditions on different lines, can use a `\multirow` for the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
  \[
    X(m,n) = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}lr@{}}
        \multirow{2}{*}{x(n),} & \text{for }0\leq n\leq 1\\
                               & \text{or }0\leq n\leq 1\\
        x(n-1), & \text{for }0\leq n\leq 1\\
        x(n-1), & \text{for }0\leq n\leq 1
        \end{array}\right\} = xy
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How comes that `x(n)` is not typeset in math mode?

Comment: @fpast Probably it's a `\multirow` collateral damage. I couldn't find information about it in LaTeX companion 2e, but `\multirow{2}{*}{$x(n),$}` solves the problem.

Comment: how does one do it with a single curly bracket in front?

Comment: @CharlieParker replace `\right\}` with `\right.`

Comment: what does `{lr}` mean?

Comment: @Ignasi your suggestion with right makes my overleaf complain that there is a missing delimiter. See my current code `\begin{equation}
steps(x^{(i)}) = 
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        x(n), & asd \\
        x(n-1), & asd \\
        x(n-1), & asd
    \end{array}
    \right
\end{equation}`

Comment: @CharlieParker The command is `\right.` . You missed the dot `.` .

Answer (score 170):

For the question as it was originally posed, we can still use `cases` very easily. We simply employ the technique of using `\left.` at the start and then we can put `\right\}` at the end:

```
\[
  X(m, n) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    x(n), & \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 1 \\
    x(n - 1), & \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 1 \\
    x(n - 1), & \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 1
  \end{cases}
  \right\} = xy
\]
```

[image]

I'm not sure that you can span rows with `cases` as in the edit, however.

Comment: that's my favourite answer, because of simplicity and keeping the original formulation with `cases`. Great job!

Comment: Apparently simple, sure, and it keeps the original `cases` environment, yes; but it does have a drawback, it inserts a spurious space (of width `\nulldelimiterspace`, usually equal to 1.2pt) both between the “=” sign and the left brace, and between the last column and tht right brace.  (Will @loved.by.Jesus read this reply posted more than two years after her/his comment?)

Comment: @GuM I read it, of course, stack-overflow notifies about replies ;). Thanks for mentioning, what I think it is the only drawback of this answer. Now the info is complete! — I wonder how you know these intricacies about LaTeX; hat off.

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: They are explained in several manuals, for example in _The TeXbook_.

Comment: how does one do it with a single curly bracket in front?

Comment: @CharlieParker just `f(x) = \begin{cases} a \\ b \end{cases}`

Comment: this results in flat text for me sometimes. Why is that? Do I need to import some package? I just copy pasted your exact code.

Comment: seems one needs this package to be imported: `\usepackage{amsmath}
` Perhaps you'd like to mention it in your answer? reference: https://www.overleaf.com/project/6070991842b7216188fa9324

Comment: In github markdown I needed to escape the right curly bracket twice like `\right\\}` to make it work.

Answer (score 21):

Essentially the same answer as Ignasi, but with the use of `\text` for the word `for`. (And with the `\leqslant` symbol of `amssymb` which I find much more elegant.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\for}{\text{for }}
\begin{document}
  \[
    X(m,n)=
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
      x(n),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1 \\
      x(n-1),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1 \\
      x(n-1),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1
    \end{array}
    \right\} = xy.
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** As for the modification recently asked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\for}{\text{for }}
\begin{document}
  \[
    X(m,n)=
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{@{}lr@{}}
      x(n),& 
      \begin{array}{r@{}}
        \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1\\ 
        \text{or } 0\leqslant x \leqslant 1
      \end{array}\\
      x(n-1),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1 \\
      x(n-1),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1
    \end{array}
    \right\} = xy.
  \]
\end{document}
```

(I didn't deem it necessary to define a new macro for the word `or` since it is written only once. Note that it seems better this time to center the second column.)

**Edit bis** Added the `@{}` specifications suggested by `daleif`. No more centering.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This has already been addressed, but I can't remember where nor when. So here is a simple solution with the `empheq` package, which loads `mathtools`, hence `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\newcommand{\for}{\text{for }}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}[right=\empheqrbrace{=xy.}]
    X(m,n)=
    \begin{cases}
      x(n),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1 \\
      x(n-1),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1 \\
      x(n-1),& \for 0\leqslant n \leqslant 1
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had errors with the package, then, in case of an **error** with the package: `\usepackage[overload]{empheq}`, consult this [link](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-optionclash)

Comment: @Antonio: Remove the `[overload]` option and use `\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace{=xy.}]{equation*}
   ......\end{empheq` instead.

Comment: I followed your variations, but if I remove `[overload]` and dispose as you suggested, the code gives me error. Eliminating `\begin{empheq}` and leaving only `\begin{equation*}` is ok

Comment: For me both have no problem.  Do you have errors with  this single code? And which errors?

Comment: i have : `\begin{empheq}\begin{equation*}[right=\empheqrbrace{=\Div{\bar{u}}=0}]....(my equation)....\begin{cases}\text{.....} \\\text{.....} \\\end{cases}\end{equation*}\end{empheq}` , the errors are: 1 ) **Missing \endcsname inserted.** `\begin` (in `\begin{equation*}),  **Environment \endcsname undefined.** \begin in (\begin{cases}) and **Undefined control sequence. \PassOptionsToPackag** in the preamble

Comment: The name of the environment, `equation*`, should be the mandatory argument of the `empheq` environment, it's not a nested environment. See the exact code in my first comment.

Comment: now it's perfect, I've been in a hurry.

Answer (score 11):

Building upon [the answer from Au101](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240911/160103), what about nesting the `cases` environments?:

```
\[
  X(m, n) = \left.
  \begin{cases}
    x(n), & 
          \begin{cases} 
                \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 1 \\
                \text{or }  0 \leq n \leq 1 
          \end{cases} \\
    x(n - 1), & \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 1 \\
    x(n - 1), & \text{for } 0 \leq n \leq 1
  \end{cases}
  \right\} = xy
\]
```

[image: LaTeX output]

The nested braces are ugly, but this approach avoids the need for the `multirow` or `array` packages.

Comment: `array` doesn't come from a separate package. It's `amsmath`, right?

Answer (score 8):

You may also want to try `\begin{Bmatrix}\end{Bmatrix}`, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    c & u & r & l & y
    \\
    b & r & a & c & e
    \\
    i & s &
    \\
    & c & o & o & l
  \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For your specific example (thanks @Mico for the hint) you can tweak the definition of ams matrix to manipulate (overall) cell-aligment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% the following two definitions allow the usage of ams matrix environments
%% with an optional argument telling how to align the matrix, useful for
%% linear algebra texts, e.g.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
   \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
   \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
 \makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  X(m,n)
  =
  \begin{Bmatrix}[l]
    x(n),
    &
    \text{ for }
    0\leq n\leq1
    \\
    x(n-1),
    &
    \text{ for }
    0\leq n\leq1
    \\
    x(n-1),
    &
    \text{ for }
    0\leq n\leq1
  \end{Bmatrix}
  =
  xy
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: I'm ignoring the fact that the math is nonsensical.]

Note that while matrix environments are easier and more straightforward to use than arrays, they are less powerful.  For example, column-dependent alignment is not easily achievable.

Comment: Please clarify how your suggestion addresses the OP's typesetting needs. E.g., please post a full example.

Comment: @Mico I've fixed my example, but the downvote still there :-(

Comment: Well, it wasn't me who downvoted, but I've upvoted the answer to remove the -1. I still think you should make the example code more relevant and applicable to the OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

I liked [@Ken’s idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425205/69818), but, once you have opted for a solution that uses nested “`cases`-like” environments, there’s an obvious improvement that permits to get rid of the additional unwanted brace, and it is to use the facilities provided by the `mathtools` package.

The `mathtools` package offers a `\newcases` command that lets you define, exactly, new “`cases`-like” environments with custom settings; in particular, it lets you specify custom delimiters on either side.  There exist already several answers on this site that describe this command (just search the site for `\newcases`), so I’ll not dwell here on the details; however, the sample code below contains comments that should suffice as a quick, essential reference.  The idea is to define two new “`cases`-like” environments, one with braces on both sides, and one with empty delimiters on both sides; remember, however, that an empty delimiter actually contributes a horizontal space of width `\nulldelimiterspace`, so you need to compensate for this by means of appropriate negative kerns.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools} % automatically loads "amsmath" too

\makeatletter

% Arguments for the "\newcases" command (from "mathtools.sty", amended):
%   #1 <- name of the new environment;
%   #2 <- separation between columns;
%   #3 <- alignment preamble (see "The TeXbook", Ch. 22), left column;
%   #4 <- alignment preamble, right column;
%   #5 <- left delimiter (e.g., "\lbrace" for the standard "cases");
%   #6 <- right delimiter (e.g., "." for the standard "cases");

% To illustrate the full range of possibilities, we'll now define *four*
% new "cases-like" environments (although we need only one of them):
% all of them have braces on both sides, but they differ in the context
% their contents are typeset in.

% Left column is math, right column is math:
\newcases{doublecases}
    {\quad}
    {$\m@th{##}$\hfil} {$\m@th{##}$\hfil}
    {\lbrace} {\rbrace}

% Left column is math, right column is text:
\newcases{doublecases*}
    {\quad}
    {$\m@th{##}$\hfil} {{##}\hfil}
    {\lbrace} {\rbrace}

% Left column is display-style math, right column is display-style math:
\newcases{ddoublecases}
    {\quad}
    {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil} {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}
    {\lbrace} {\rbrace}

% Left column is display-style math, right column is text:
\newcases{ddoublecases*}
    {\quad}
    {$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil} {{##}\hfil}
    {\lbrace} {\rbrace}

% For the case (!) of the "case-like" environment with empty delimiters
% on both sides, however, we define only the variant we actually need:

% Left column is right-aligned text, right column... doesn't matter:
\newcases{nullcases}
    {\quad}
    {\hfil{##}} {{##}\hfil}
    {.} {.}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Some text before the equation.
\[
    X(m, n) =
        \begin{ddoublecases}
            x(n), & 
                    \kern -\nulldelimiterspace
                    \begin{nullcases} % beware of spaces!
                        for $0 \leq n \leq 1$\\
                        or $0 \leq n \leq 1$%
                    \end{nullcases}
                    \kern -\nulldelimiterspace
                \\
            x(n - 1), & \text{for $0 \leq n \leq 1$} \\
            x(n - 1), & \text{for $0 \leq n \leq 1$}
        \end{ddoublecases}
    = xy
\]
Some text after the equation.

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 0):

```
\delta_{nm}=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if } m=n,\\
0, & \text{ ow.}
\end{cases}
```

[image: Output 1]

If you want the exact output, including the closing braces for the cases, as well as the two conditions for the first case, you can use package delarray as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
X(m, n)=
\begin{array}\{{ll}\}
x(n), & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
x(n-1), & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 
x(n-1), & \text { for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
\end{array}=xy
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
X(m, n)=
\begin{array}\{{rl}\}
x(n), & {\begin{matrix}\text{ for }0 \leq x \leq 1 \\\text{ or }0 \leq x \leq 1 \end{matrix}} \\
x(n-1), & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 
x(n-1), & \text { for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
\end{array}=xy
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output 2]

This package allows you to specify the position of each element in the array cell, as well as the delimiters for the entire array, in your case the curly braces spanning all three cases.

Comment: There's no need for `eqnarray`. Instead, just use `\[`...`\]`.