# How to get big curly braces for an equation with 3 parts?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, delimiters

I am very new to LaTeX. I want to display this:

[image]

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you already have some code that you could add for people to get started more easily? Have you tried the `cases` environment from the _amsmath_ package?

Comment: I haven't tried `cases` environment. I will do that and add my code here.

Comment: It looks quite like what you want. Alternatively, you can use `\left\{ <content> \right.` as shown for instance [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}V_i(t) = \max \left\{
\begin{array}{@{}rl@{}}
\text{abandon:} & 0;\\
\text{continue:}&-c(t)+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^N[pV_{i+j/2}(t+2)+(1-p)V_{i-j/2}(t+1)]}{N(1+r)};   \\[1ex]
\text{improve:} &-c(t)-\alpha(t) \\
                &\hfill{}+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^N[pV_{i+1+j/2}(t+2)+(1-p)V_{i+1-j/2}(t+1)]}{N(1+r)}.
\end{array}
\right .
\end{equation}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little hard to get right for a beginner, here is some of it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \max
  \begin{cases}
    \! % artifact from aligned(at)
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
      &\text{apandon:} &\quad & 0;
      \\
      &\text{continue:} && \frac{A}{B} ;
      \\
      &\text{improve:} && A + B 
      \\
      &&& +C;
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture please? I always like to see on the forst look what the output would look like.

Comment: Oh, lol, I assumed the +c was just something that happened due to line break, not something that was intentionally on the next line

Answer (score 4):

One more alternative (based on use of  `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
    \[
    V_i(t) = \max\begin{dcases}
    \mathrm{apandon:}   &  0;                    \\
    \mathrm{continue:}  &  \frac{A}{B} ;         \\
    \mathrm{improve:}   &  \begin{multlined}[t] A + B\\  +C+D+E+F\end{multlined}
      \end{dcases}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

[image]