# Adding a bracket to a set of equations

Tags: equations, lists, brackets

So I'm a first time Latex learner and I'm still learning the roots, but I want to do something similar to the example given in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Which aspects of this screenshot are you trying to reproduce? The curly brace down the left-hand side, the colons, the alignment of the three equations, how to to place material in a subscript position, or something else? Please be specific.

Comment: Please see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47170/how-to-write-conditional-equations-with-one-sided-curly-brackets?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Au101 - As of now, it's not clear *which* part, or parts, of the screenshot the OP is looking to reproduce. The curly brace is only of several possible style elements... Let's see if the OP responds to my inquiry. If we don't get an answer, the posting can be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @Mico You make a fair point, but the title does say "adding a bracket to a set of equations" ... D. Brito you'd definitely benefit from having a quick read through the links in any case :)

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to add the curly brace down the left together with the equations. I'm sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @D.Brito sure so check out the links, the basic syntax you want is `\[ \begin{cases} \ell_{1} : a_{1}x ... \\ \ell_{2} : a_{2}x ... ... \end{cases} \]`. Unless of course you have any additional requirements

Comment: Alternatively I guess you could use an array `\[ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} \ell_{1} : a_{1}x ... ... ... \end{array} \right. \]`

Comment: Ok, thanks, the cases seemed to do the trick. Although I'll also check out the array.

Comment: I really don't understand why this notation is still around. A brace that is linked to nothing is visually a very bad notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 y & = x\\
 z & = a.
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

*** EDIT ***

As Werner commented, you can alternatively use the cases or dcases environments; the latter needs the mathtools package. The cases environment is really intended for the end of a line with something else in front.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
 y & = x\\
 z & = a.
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
y  = x\\
z  = a.
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `cases` or `dcases` seem appropriate here...

Comment: I don't think cases is right unless there's something to the left of the \{, like f(x)=...  dcases works, but I've often had the need for the somewhat more flexible and general construct I used in the original example.