# How do I typeset a set with multiple conditions

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to learn as how to typeset for such a expression in latex. [image]

Thank you

Comment: Please don't post screen shots. Instead, post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This allow people to cut and paste your code and hence trouble shoot. In particular, MWEs should be compilable latex code.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240870/1952

Comment: @Ignasi not quite related as the first part is vertically centered.

Comment: @daleif That's why `multirow` is used in second example.

Comment: @Ignasi compare the amount of typing to using `aligned` (as suggested by campa)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `amsmath` here is one method (only the brace part, the rest is up to you)

I agree with Andrew, we don't really like questions of the sort: "please make this for me", there should some effort.

Here I've just given the foundation (`memoir` is irrelevant, just my default class)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
     (D_1,D_2,D_0): 
     \begin{aligned}
       & A \\ & B \\ & C \\ & D  \\ & E \\ & F
     \end{aligned}
  \right\}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

Addition: If you have several set definitions in your doc, it might be an idea to make a syntax for it. This is an adaption of an example in the `mathtools` manual:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\providecommand\given{}
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{:}
% see the mathtools manual for a definition of \SetSymbol that works
% with |
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{
  \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \Set*{
     (D_1,D_2,D_0)
     \given
     \begin{aligned}
       & A \\ & B \\ & C \\ & D  \\ & E \\ & F
     \end{aligned}
  }
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

First possibility:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.33333}
  S = \left\{
    (D_1,D_2,D_0) :
    \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.}} \\ 
      \hat{X}_1 = f_1(Y_1),\\
      \hat{X}_2 = f_2(Y_2),\\
      D_1 \geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)],\\
      D_2 \geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)],\\
      D_0 \geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)],
    \end{array}
  \right\}
  ,
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Output of the first code sample]

But the printout shown in the picture is probably generated by

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  S \triangleq \left\{
    (D_1,D_2,D_0) :
    \begin{aligned}
      &\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.} \\ 
      \hat{X}_1 &= f_1(Y_1),\\
      \hat{X}_2 &= f_2(Y_2),\\
      D_1 &\geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)],\\
      D_2 &\geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)],\\
      D_0 &\geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)],
    \end{aligned}
  \right\}
  ,
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Indeed, this time the output is

[image: Output of the second code sample]

---

## Addition

Just for fun, here is how I would implement @daleif’s suggestion of using a general-purpose command like `\Set`.

The following code defines two “style declarations”:

- when `\ColonSets` is in force, the separator between the two parts
  of the definition of a set is a colon (this is the default);
- when `\MvertSets` is in force, the separator is a vertical bar.

The `\Set` command can be employed as usual, that is:

- in its starred form (*i.e.*, `\Set*{...}{...}`) it provides
  auto-sizing braces (and vertical bar, if appropriate);
- with an optional argument (*e.g.*, `\Set[\Big]{...}{...}`),
  a size specification can be passed in that argument, which is
  applied to the braces, and to the vertical bar if applicable.

Moreover, I have followed the advice given in footnote 9 on page 27 of the `mathtools` manual, of providing an independent command, named `\SetSuchThat`, that typeset the separator, with an optional scale modifier.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\newcommand*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand*{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand*{\No}{\N_{0}}

\newcommand*{\SetSuchThat}[1][]{} % reserve the name
\newcommand*{\ColonSets}{%
    \renewcommand*\SetSuchThat[1][]{:}%
}
\newcommand*{\MvertSets}{%
    \renewcommand*\SetSuchThat[1][]{%
        \mathclose{}%
        \nonscript\;##1\vert\penalty\relpenalty\nonscript\;%
        \mathopen{}%
    }%
}
\ColonSets % default
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX \Set [2] {\lbrace}{\rbrace}
    {\,#1\SetSuchThat[\delimsize]#2\,}



\begin{document}

Description of a set: \( X = \Set*{\frac{n-1}{n}}{n\in\No} \).

A ``handmade'' version, which permits line breaks within itself:
\( X = \bigl\{\, \frac{n+1}{n} \SetSuchThat[\big] n\in\No \,\bigr\} \).

Second ``handmade'' version, again unbreakable:
\( X = \mleft\{ \frac{n+2}{n} \SetSuchThat[\middle] n\in\No \mright\} \).

The ``big set'' written first with \texttt{array}
\begin{equation*}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    S \triangleq
    \Set*{(D_1,D_2,D_0)}{
        \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.}} \\ 
            \hat{X}_1 = f_1(Y_1), \\
            \hat{X}_2 = f_2(Y_2), \\
            D_1 \geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)], \\
            D_2 \geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)], \\
            D_0 \geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)]
        \end{array}
    }
    ,
\end{equation*}
and then with \texttt{aligned}
\begin{equation*}
    S \triangleq
    \Set*{(D_1,D_2,D_0)}{
        \begin{aligned}
            &\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.} \\ 
            \hat{X}_1 &= f_1(Y_1), \\
            \hat{X}_2 &= f_2(Y_2), \\
            D_1 &\geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)], \\
            D_2 &\geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)], \\
            D_0 &\geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)]
        \end{aligned}
    }
    .
\end{equation*}

Now we'll repeat the whole thing with the \verb|\MvertSets| declaration in
force.

\bigbreak

\MvertSets

Description of a set: \( X = \Set*{\frac{n-1}{n}}{n\in\No} \).

A ``handmade'' version, which permits line breaks within itself:
\( X = \bigl\{\, \frac{n+1}{n} \SetSuchThat[\big] n\in\No \,\bigr\} \).

Second ``handmade'' version, again unbreakable:
\( X = \mleft\{ \frac{n+2}{n} \SetSuchThat[\middle] n\in\No \mright\} \).

The ``big set'' written first with \texttt{array}
\begin{equation*}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    S \triangleq
    \Set*{(D_1,D_2,D_0)}{
        \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.}} \\ 
            \hat{X}_1 = f_1(Y_1), \\
            \hat{X}_2 = f_2(Y_2), \\
            D_1 \geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)], \\
            D_2 \geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)], \\
            D_0 \geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)]
        \end{array}
    }
    ,
\end{equation*}
and then with \texttt{aligned}
\begin{equation*}
    S \triangleq
    \Set*{(D_1,D_2,D_0)}{
        \begin{aligned}
            &\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.} \\ 
            \hat{X}_1 &= f_1(Y_1), \\
            \hat{X}_2 &= f_2(Y_2), \\
            D_1 &\geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)], \\
            D_2 &\geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)], \\
            D_0 &\geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)]
        \end{aligned}
    }
    .
\end{equation*}

IMHO\@, the first alternative looks better!

\end{document}
```

The output follows:

[image: Output of the third code sample]

### Comment

I’ve edited the code in the third example in order to achieve the correct spacing also in “unusual” situations (see addition of `\mathclose{}` and `mathopen{}`.  Moreover, it should be remarked that it is very easy to implement Barbara Beeton’s suggestion of increasing the space on the right of the colon in the “big set” description, if you feel so inclined: it suffices to add an explicit spacing command, *e.g.* `\;`, at the beginning of the second argument of the `\Set` command, like this:

```
\Set*{(D_1,D_2,D_0)}{\; % <-- added space
    \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.}} \\ 
        \hat{X}_1 = f_1(Y_1), \\
        \hat{X}_2 = f_2(Y_2), \\
        D_1 \geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)], \\
        D_2 \geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)], \\
        D_0 \geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)]
    \end{array}
}
```

You might also want to add a similar amount of space at the end of the first argument; for example, here is how to add a thin space:

```
\Set*{(D_1,D_2,D_0)\,}{\; % <-- look here
    \begin{aligned}
        &\exists f_{1}, f_{2} \text{ s.t.} \\ 
        \hat{X}_1 &= f_1(Y_1), \\
        \hat{X}_2 &= f_2(Y_2), \\
        D_1 &\geq \E[d_1(X,\hat{X}_1)], \\
        D_2 &\geq \E[d_2(X,\hat{X}_2)], \\
        D_0 &\geq \E[d_0(\hat{X}_1,\hat{X}_2)]
    \end{aligned}
}
```

Comment: you missed the triangle over the `=` ;-)

Comment: @daleif: What triangle?  **Edit:** Ah, the first “=”; I can’t remember off the top of my head what’s the name of that symbol.

Comment: @daleif: The name of that relation symbol turned out to be quite obvious: `\triangleq`.

Comment: some additional space following the colon would be an improvement.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I’m not sure it would.  IMHO, the spacing around the colon shoud be symmetrical.  In any case, it’s very easy to replace `:` with, say, `:\,`… :-)  Thank you for your comment, anyway.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- i'm just comparing with the appearance in the question.  yes, i see that it's symmetrical there, or very nearly so.  what i was mainly commenting on is the fact that the left hand side is very close to the right-hand side -- too close for comfortable reading and interpretation, i think.

Comment: Trust me at some point you'll get tired of writing this as two arguments. IMO it reads more naturally with the `\given` syntax presented in the mathtools manual

Comment: @daleif: May be, but I find it more logical with two arguments, at least for now. (:-)  More important: I’ve noticed that I have forgotten the `\mathopen{}` in the definition of `\SetSuchThat`: I’ll fix this tomorrow, now I’m going to bed…