# Increasing the size of a symbol "|"

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX, and I'm trying to create a large `|`, as shown in the following image:

[image]

If I'll use:

```
G=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}t & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix}|t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\right\}
```

I would get:

[image]

Is it possible to make the `|` symbol larger without using any external modules?

Comment: This question reminds me of something similar: was it, perhaps, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333471/69818)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\middle|`, and you have to add some horizontal spacing on the right and on the left.

Even if you don't want to use external package modules, I suggest using the `DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` (which is just an extension of `amsmath`, which takes care of all the spacing problems, and  loading `xparse` to simplify the syntax (both arguments are separated by  a `;`). Here is a code for each solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, mathtools, amsfonts}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

 \begin{document}

\[ G=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}t & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\, t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\right\} \]
\bigskip

\[ G=\set*{ \begin{pmatrix}t & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix} ; t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}} \]

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

First off, I would use inline-fraction notation, `1/t`, instead of `\frac{1}{t}` in order to typeset the matrix more compactly. If you're OK with using `psmallmatrix` instead of `pmatrix`, you can then get by with `\bigl(`, `\bigm|` (or `\bigm\vert`), and `\bigr)`. If you prefer using `pmatrix`, use `\biggl(`, `\biggm|`, and `\biggr)` instead.

[image]

Observe that `\biggm|` automatically adds the typographically required amount of whitespace around the vertical bar. This is in contrast to `\bigg|`, wwhere no whitespace is inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'psmallmatrix' env.
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for '\mathbb' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
G&=\bigl\{ 
\begin{psmallmatrix} t & 0\\ 0 & 1/t \end{psmallmatrix} 
\bigm| 
t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times} 
\bigr\} \\
&=\biggl\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} t & 0\\ 0 & 1/t \end{pmatrix} 
\biggm| 
t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times} 
\biggr\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is a Lyx-specific issue.  Does this work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$
G=\left\{
\left. %ADDED (as a blank bracket)
\begin{pmatrix}
t & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix}
\right| %ADDED (as expandable bracket)
t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\right\}
$

\end{document}
```

[image: Extra brackets]

The way this works is be wrapping another set of brackets around the `pmatrix` environment.  The first one is empty (`\left.`) while the you replace the current `|` as the companion right bracket (`\right|`).  This allows it to match the height automatically.

Answer (score 6):

For to increase simply  the `|` symbol an alternative might be to use the commands `\bigg\vert`, or `\Bigg\vert`. See the my MWE with the picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
G=\Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} t & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix} \bigg\vert
      \,t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\Biggr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

**2nd example:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
G=\Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} t & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{t}
\end{pmatrix} \Bigg\vert
      \,t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\Biggr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you write `\Biggm\vert` instead of `\Bigg\vert`, one needn't engage in visual formatting by inserting a `\,` instruction.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your comment. I saw your answer that I appreciated so much. I absolutely did not know of the existence of `\biggm`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if an `array` is OK to use or not, but this is simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}    
\begin{document}

\[
G=\left\{\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
\begin{pmatrix} t & 0\\ 0 & \frac1t \end{pmatrix} & t\in\mathbb{R}^\times
\end{array}\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]