# How to write two rows clip

Tags: math-mode, equations, parentheses

how can I please write this? I can't find the right name to find it in instructions. Thank you. [image: Look at picture]

Comment: have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex helps

Comment: It is called an accolade, see also the question in the comment by samcarter. For your case, you could for instance use `$abc = \left\{ \begin{aligned} d \\ e \end{aligned} \right.$`

Comment: Off-topic: units should be set upright. Either do this manually using `\mathrm{}` or use the `siunitx` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain what you want with the `empheq` package (needless to load `amsmath` nor `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand{\MeV}{\mathrm{MeV}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left ={\dfrac{R_\beta\cdot\rho}{\mathrm{g\cdot cm^{-2}}} =\empheqlbrace}]{alignat* = 2}
& 0{,}407\,(E_0/\MeV)^{1{,}38} & 0{,}15 < E_0 & \le 0{,}8\,\MeV \\
& 0{,}542\,(E_0/\MeV)-0{,}133 & E_0 & > 0{,}8\,\MeV
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]