# LaTeX beamer problem with equations centered inside braces

Tags: beamer, brackets, alignment

I just recently started to use Latex, so I'am having some problems with the equation environment. In specific, I want to put three different equations inside brackets, but I want then to be center aligned. In Word, It would be something like this:

[image]

The problem is that I'am having some trouble doing this with Latex. I've tried to use Gather, but it didn't work as I expected... Can someone help me, please? Thank you very much.

Here is part of the code that I'am using:

````
\begin{gather}
    1, \mbox{ if } \pi_{t}^{e}=\pi_{t}^c \\
    0, \mbox{ if } \pi_{t}^{e}>\pi_{tMAX}^{*} \mbox{ ou } \pi_{t}^{e}<\pi_{tMIN}^{*}
\end{gather}


\end{frame}```
````

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240868/how-to-write-cases-with-latex

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't use a `gather` environment. Instead, I'd load the `mathtools` package and use its `dcases*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
x=
\begin{dcases*}
  1 & if $\pi_t^{e}=\pi_t^c$ \\
  0 & if $\pi_t^{e}>\pi_{t_{\max}}^{*}$ or $\pi_t^{e}<\pi_{t_{\min}}^{*}$
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: You could use a `Bmatrix` environment to achieve the stated formatting objective:

[image]

```
x = \begin{Bmatrix}
  1, \text{ if } \pi_t^{e}=\pi_t^c \\
  0, \text{ if } \pi_t^{e}>\pi_{t_{\max}}^{*} \text{ or } \pi_t^{e}<\pi_{t_{\min}}^{*}
\end{Bmatrix}
```

Comment: I understand Nico, but I want my equations to be aligned in the center of the brackets... That's my problem. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @PedroCrispim - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: @PedroCrispim I get that you want it centered, but I find the non-centered part, where the equations are aligned on the beginning of the conditional statement, far easier to read.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much for your attention! And Tristan, thank you for your comment, I will consider it!. Regards!

Answer (score 5):

`Bmatrix` can be used to center equations between braces.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
  1, \text{ if } \pi_{t}^{e}=\pi_{t}^c \\
  0, \text{ if } \pi_{t}^{e}>\pi_{t_{\max}}^{*} \text{ ou } \pi_{t}^{e}<\pi_{t_{\min}}^{*}
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]